# Top 5 numbers in the same row from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have column names with a letter from a-z.  each column get a number put into it.  I want to look at a row and determine which columns have the top 5 numbers.

```
a  b    c   d   e   f  g  h

5  10  20  15  35  40 85 75
```

should return top rows= g,h,f,e,c

i have seen this done for mysql, looking to do this for php.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you actively pulling the data from mysql? You should focus your question to be just about the part you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're selecting all the columns from the database, which would give you an array like the following:

```
$array  = [
    'a' => 5,
    'b' => 10,
    'c' => 20,
    'd' => 15,
    'e' => 35,
    'f' => 40,
    'g' => 85,
    'h' => 75,
];
```

...this will sort them and remove all but the highest 5 results:

```
arsort($array);
$result = array_slice($array, 0, 5, true);
```

You can then use `array_keys($array)` to get the column names.